# Why my radio buttons are not taking if else statement in javascript file?

Tags: javascript

```
    <input id="text1" placeholder="Enter Anything">
    <input id="rd1" name="grp1" type="radio" value="gurukul">Gurukul</input>
    <input id="rd2" name="grp1" type="radio" value="NEET">NEET</input>
     <br>
    <button onclick="fn1()"  id="btn1">Click Me</button>
```

Code for Js file is

```
function fn1()
    {
        var str = document.getElementById("text1").value;
        var rd1 = document.getElementById("rd1").value;
        var rd2 = document.getElementById("rd2").value;

        if(rd1.checked){
            alert("Value inside the text box is"+ str + "Welcome to"+rd1.value);
        }
        else if(rd2.checked){
            alert("Value inside the text box is"+ str + "Welcome to"+rd2.value);
        }
        else {
            alert("Value inside the text box is"+ str +  "No channel selected");
        }
    }
```

But any radio button i select , No channel selected option come out. Why is it so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `rd1` is an `element.value`, then it's a string and does not have a `.checked` property (it's undefined => false).

Remove `.value` from the assignment:

> var rd1 = document.getElementById("rd1").value;

```
var rd1 = document.getElementById("rd1");
```

Answer (score -3):

Change the if condition like this if(rd1.checked = true)

Comment: That's an assignment. It will always resolve as true … and (if `rd1` was a checkbox and not a string) check the checkbox as it goes.